# EasyBox Packet Loss, especially under pressure

Tags: router, packet-loss

the problem in itself seems very straightforward, but I can't find the cause. It started a few weeks ago, and ever since every device in the network experiences packet loss. If you just do casual stuff, say, checking wikipedia or the like, there might be 0,1% loss or even less. But as soon as you start some big download or an online game, the packet loss skyrockets, making games unplayable. It doesn't stay on this consistent high loss though, after a few minutes it usually works fine again until it just randomly reappears, but giving him high pressure, like a game patch, triggers some initial package loss pretty consistently.

This happens on multiple machines, some connected by WLAN, even on the one directly with LAN, and the packet gets always lost between the device and the router. That's why I can only assume that it's some Router-internal problem. Restarting/Resetting the router doesn't do anything, and I haven't seen anything in the router settings that looks helful. There is also no warning light or anything activated on the router.

An idea I had was that maybe some QoS setting might be responsible, but that doesn't even come up in this version of the firmware. The Box is a Vodafone EasyBox 904 xDSL.

Any idea is very much appreciated, as I just have no more clue where to look at. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that the packets are being dropped between the router and the modem? DSL is notorious for dropping packets when the line quality is low.

You can't connect your modem directly to your computer to check because it's integrated... but if you have another DSL modem, I'd try connecting it directly to a computer. If it works fine, the router is the culprit for sure.

as a side note: most ISPs can run a line quality check. Calling up your provider and asking them to run a check might be helpful.

Comment: I checked it by running simultaneous ping tests on the router itself, which is the first hop after each device, and google.com. If i just hold the cmd windows next to each others, it's pretty clear that when I get a loss on the google ping, I also get a loss just pinging the router. (The google ping isn't even necessary...just pinging the router while downlowding something is enough to see tons of loss. And yes, the router does accept pings.)
Haven't got another modem sadly, so can't test that for now. Calling the provider is...a huge time investment, maybe on the weekend.

Comment: okay, that's pretty definitive. Sounds like there might be a problem with the router. I know that sucks, but you've done all the tests you can do. 

I'd check and see if there is a firmware upgrade, but other then that it might be time to buy another.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for your time then, atleast I got another opinion on it.